# MEF in multiple exports of same type not working (but they work individually)

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I have an interface IInterfaceA which a class ClassA implements.  3 more classes then derive from ClassA - ClassA1, ClassA2 and ClassA3 - which are all in separate project DLLs.

I now have a Windows Service (launched by using TopShelf in a console App) which has this at the top of the Program class of the console app:

```
[ImportMany]
public List<IInterfaceA> importsList { get; set; }
```

And in a function called from an instance of Program created in the Main function, I do the following:

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path);
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
container.ComposeParts(this);
```

If I put say ClassA1.dll in the catalog directory the ComposeParts will work fine and there will be one item in importsList.  The same will happen if I put JUST ClassA2.dll or JUST ClassA3.dll in the catalog directory - the MEF code works fine.

BUT - if I put more than one of the DLLs in, say ClassA1.dll AND ClassA2.dll - the MEF fails and there's no items in the importsList.  It doesn't throw any MEF errors/exceptions though - it just doesn't work.

Anyone seen this before and know why?  Could it be because the base ClassA class is MEF'ing in types from other projects and also those MEF'd in types are also MEF'ing in types from elsewhere - i.e. there's about 3 levels deep of MEF'ing going on!

Thanks

Comment: can you show us your class and interface implementation?

Comment: @trembler2003: How do you define your exports? Anything special there? Class and interface implementations would help!

Comment: The scenario you describe is working fine for me. I have `InterfaceA` and `ClassA` in the host application and two other libraries with classes derived from `ClassA`. The host application always finds all it should from the available DLLs. I suppose there will be something wrong with how you do the exports inheritance. Please provide the implementation details of the `InterfaceA` and the derived classes. Can't help you further without that.